# First page number is 0 in the API response when using spring data one-indexed-parameters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-jpa` to developing a REST API.
I am trying to make an API page start from 1 instead of 0.

I configured the following property `spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=true` in `application.properties` file.

Here is my current endpoint implementation code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/alluser", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public Page<User> getUserinfo(Pageable pageable) 
 {
      Page<User> userPage = userService.getAllUserInfo(pageable);
      List<User> userResultList = userPage.getContent();
      userResultList = userResultList.stream().map(userObj -> {
          converterService.convertToDto(userObj);
      return userObj;
      }).collect(Collectors.toList());

      Page<User> userDtoPage = new PageImpl<>(userResultList, pageable, userPage.getTotalElements());
      return userDtoPage;
 }
```

When the above REST endpoint is invoked as below

http://localhost:9091/user-management/userinfo/alluser

Then I get the following response

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "userId": "111",
      "userName": "First Demo"
    },
    {
      "userId": "222",
      "userName": "Second Demo"
    }
  ],
  "pageable": {
    "sort": {
      "empty": true,
      "sorted": false,
      "unsorted": true
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 2,
    "paged": true,
    "unpaged": false
  },
  "last": false,
  "totalElements": 8,
  "totalPages": 4,
  "size": 2,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": {
    "empty": true,
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true
  },
  "first": true,
  "numberOfElements": 2,
  "empty": false
}
```

I am expecting the `pageNumber` to be 1, however it is 0.

Comment: Hello, please explain what do you mean exactly with "to make an API page start from 1 instead of 0"? How is your current endpoint implemented? Please paste formatted as a code snippet.

Comment: Please also add some examples how are you calling the endpoint, what parameter you use for the first page and what is the response? Both the actual and the expected one. Because it is still not clear for us what behavior do you expect.

Comment: Thanks @Mar-Z for you quick response. Sorry for late reply. I updated the details.